# What is gained from resetting in Bitcoin Billionaire?

Tags: bitcoin-billionaire

I see that sometimes there are bonuses that last even after a reset. But why would anyone reset? Is there some sort of bonus system like Cookie Clicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting at bitminer v25 gives you a 20% bonus in the new game, this stacks after doing it again. You get to keep the bonus the achievements give you as well.